# Php - How can i print a image using printf?

Tags: php

Im trying to print a image using printf, but it doesnt work.

The column "imagem" show the directory of the image.

```
function listaCDs() {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cds`";
            if(($rs=$this->bd->executarSQL($sql))){

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


                              printf("


                            <img src=%s height="100" width="100" />", $row['imagem']);
                              echo "<br>";
                        }

            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: HTML attributes should be in quotes. That includes the `src`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
printf("<img src=%s height='100' width='100' />", $row['imagem']);
```

instead of

```
printf("<img src=%s height="100" width="100" />", $row['imagem']);
```

You have double `quotes` inside double `quotes` for attributes, which is the problem. Check [this demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DVetgN)

Comment: This will fail if `$row['imagem']` contain spaces.

Comment: @PauloFreitas, This is an `url/http://example.com/img.png` so, there is no chance for this.

Comment: You can't assure that. Filenames can contain spaces and you aren't encoding them.

Comment: @PauloFreitas, do you use a space in a file name ?

Comment: I think most browsers will handle the spaces fine these days, no? Otherwise just wrap `urlencode($row['imagem'])`

Comment: Agreed @ButtleButkus :-)

Comment: @RCV Can you ensure all your users won't use them? Do you know from where this piece of code came from? If you don't use quotes nor encode contents, SGML parsers won't parse as you're expecting. Simply that.

Comment: This is how ANY SGML (HTML/XHTML/XML/DTD/anything-like-that) parser works: https://eval.in/66163

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
printf("<img src='%s' height='100' width='100' />", $row['imagem']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image's directory is public (i.e copy and paste $row['imagem'] in a browser to see if it's accessible).